# Como somar registro atual ao registro anterior,criando um acumulativo?

Tags: php, mysql

Como somar registro atual ao registro anterior,criando um acumulativo?

```
SELECT 
        DAY(i.imp_data) AS DATA,
        m.mt_valor / m.mt_valor / CAST(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) AS DECIMAL)* 100 AS META_DIARIA,
        SUM(i.imp_venda) / m.mt_valor * 100 AS VENDA
    FROM
        metas AS m
            LEFT JOIN
        importacao AS i ON m.mt_loja = i.imp_loja
    WHERE
        m.mt_loja = 1
    GROUP BY i.imp_data , i.imp_loja ;
```

O select acima retorna:

```
1   3.3333333333    4.289370
2   3.3333333333    4.469177
3   3.3333333333    6.114472
4   3.3333333333    2.988198
5   3.3333333333    2.903717
6   3.3333333333    4.254977
7   3.3333333333    2.825020
8   3.3333333333    4.320407
9   3.3333333333    3.985957
10  3.3333333333    5.961010
11  3.3333333333    2.829374
12  3.3333333333    2.855886
13  3.3333333333    2.859196
14  3.3333333333    2.812158
15  3.3333333333    4.580555
16  3.3333333333    3.297720
17  3.3333333333    4.736971
18  3.3333333333    2.325877
19  3.3333333333    2.488738
20  3.3333333333    2.059191
```

Quero somar: registro 1 + registro 2

```
1   3.3333333333    4.289370
2   3.3333333333    4.469177

    66.666.666.666  8.758.547
```

E assim por diante:

```
1   3.3333333333    4.289370
2   3.3333333333    4.469177
3   3.3333333333    6.114472
4   3.3333333333    2.988198
5   3.3333333333    2.903717
6   3.3333333333    4.254977
   199.999.999.998  25.019.911



    MT 1            MT2          ACUM 1         ACUM 2
1   33.333.333.333  6.114.472   33.333.333.333  6.114.472
2   33.333.333.333  2.988.198   66.666.666.666  9.102.670
3   33.333.333.333  2.903.717   99.999.999.999  12.006.387
4   33.333.333.333  4.254.977   133.333.333.332 16.261.364
```

Comment: o seu acumulativo vai ser a soma de todas as linas retornadas ?

Comment: sim, vou editar a pergunta para mostrar como poderia ser

Comment: Faça isso no PHP, acredito que você tem uma lista desse objeto depois que faz a busca no banco, bastaria você adicionar mais uma linha na lista com a soma dos campos, mas tem um detalhes, seu campo tem valores altos, isso pode estourar o tamanho de alguns tipos de variáveis.

Comment: @ GOKU SSJGod olha a pergunta,editei ela, veja o que aconteceu, poderia me mostrar um exemplo em php, porque na verdade eu to usando isso em um dashboard da google.

Comment: Ah, entendi. você que mais duas colunas ..

Comment: não,as colunas coloquei como exemplo para você,de como poderia ser

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45721/discussion-between-otacio-barbosa-and-goku-ssjgod).

Comment: Tem soluções bem comuns, com @variáveis e com UNION ALL. Mais simples ainda seria somar no PHP. De qq forma seria bom dar uma otimizada na sua _query_. Teria como você postar um modelo mínimo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), com pelo menos umas 10 linhas de dado? Facilitaria como ponto de partida. Outra coisa, qual a finalidade de `m.mt_valor / m.mt_valor` na sua query? Me parece redundante, pois isso resulta em 1, não? E tem mais uma questão: se é para usar `WHERE m.mt_loja = (numero de uma loja só)`, daria para simplicar o `LEFT JOIN importacao AS i ON m.mt_loja = i.imp_loja`.

Comment: Oi @Bacco fiz realmente a soma e deu certo obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou com muito tempo para pensar em algo melhor agora, mas isso resolve.

Espero que alguém der uma resposta melhor.

```
  SELECT 
            DAY(i.imp_data) AS DATA,
            m.mt_valor / m.mt_valor / CAST(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) AS DECIMAL)* 100 AS META_DIARIA,
            SUM(i.imp_venda) / m.mt_valor * 100 AS VENDA
        FROM
            metas AS m
                LEFT JOIN
            importacao AS i ON m.mt_loja = i.imp_loja
        WHERE
            m.mt_loja = 1
        GROUP BY i.imp_data , i.imp_loja
    Union all

    Select 0 , sum(d.META_DIARIA), sum(d.VENDA)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
            DAY(i.imp_data) AS DATA,
            m.mt_valor / m.mt_valor / CAST(DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) AS DECIMAL)* 100 AS META_DIARIA,
            SUM(i.imp_venda) / m.mt_valor * 100 AS VENDA
        FROM
            metas AS m
                LEFT JOIN
            importacao AS i ON m.mt_loja = i.imp_loja
        WHERE
            m.mt_loja = 1
        GROUP BY i.imp_data , i.imp_loja 
    )d;
```

Você pode montar um cursor conforme o exemplo abaixo.

```
declare @teste table
(
  DATA int,
  META_DIARIA float,
  VENDA float
)


declare @testeAux table -- crie uma tabela auxiliar
(
  DATA int,
  META_DIARIA float,
  VENDA float
)

insert into @teste values

(1, 3.3333333333,4.289370),
(2, 3.3333333333,4.469177),
(3, 3.3333333333,6.114472),
(4, 3.3333333333,2.988198),
(5, 3.3333333333,2.903717),
(6, 3.3333333333,4.254977),
(7, 3.3333333333,2.825020),
(8, 3.3333333333,4.320407),
(9, 3.3333333333,3.985957),
(10,3.3333333333,5.961010),
(11,3.3333333333,2.829374),
(12,3.3333333333,2.855886),
(13,3.3333333333,2.859196),
(14,3.3333333333,2.812158),
(15,3.3333333333,4.580555),
(16,3.3333333333,3.297720),
(17,3.3333333333,4.736971),
(18,3.3333333333,2.325877),
(19,3.3333333333,2.488738),
(20,3.3333333333,2.059191)

declare @DATA int,  @META_DIARIA float,  @VENDA float
DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR   
select DATA,  META_DIARIA,  VENDA   from @teste -- altere para seu select existente


OPEN product_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @DATA,  @META_DIARIA,  @VENDA  


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    insert into @testeAux (DATA,  META_DIARIA,  VENDA) 
    values (@DATA,  @META_DIARIA,  @VENDA );

    insert into @testeAux ( META_DIARIA,  VENDA) 
    select sum(META_DIARIA),  sum(VENDA)  from @testeAux where DATA is not null;

    FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @DATA,  @META_DIARIA,  @VENDA    
    END  

CLOSE product_cursor  
DEALLOCATE product_cursor  

select * from @testeAux
```

Esse exemplo foi montado em sql server, acredito não não seja algo dificil de você monta-lo em mysql.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Conforme falei [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154213/como-somar-registro-atual-ao-registro-anterior-criando-um-acumulativo/154218#comment318367_154213), isso pode provocar um erro devido o tamanho da variável.

Comment: Consegui acertar seu select,mais na verdade vc fez uma soma total,não preciso do total,preciso que eles acumulem 1 a 1

Comment: Estou estudando seu código para entender e aplicar ao que preciso,mais pelo que já to vendo sairá o resultado esperado,por enquanto fiz em php. Obrigado novamente.